# ARMA GARCH fitting

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, arima, garch, parameterization

I've made a few posts regarding a manual ARMA GARCH implementation and I have made some great progress. However, I am still shy of a working program as I am obtaining some rather large forecasts. I've also noticed extreme sensitivity to my initial guess for the optimization. For notations sake, here is the ARMA (1,1) model I am following:

$$X_t = \mu +  \varphi X_{t-1} +  \theta\epsilon_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$$

and the GARCH(1,1) model:

$$ \sigma^2_t = \omega + \alpha \epsilon_{t-1}^2 + \beta \sigma_{t-1}^2$$

Here is the function I am calling to be optimized. Instead of using OLS for the ARMA, I am instead constructing ARMA GARCH simultaneously. I am working in Python.

```
def ARMA_GARCH(returns, mu, theta, phi, omega, alpha, beta):
    # ARMA Portion
    resid = np.zeros(len(returns))
    for i in range(len(returns)-1):
        resid[i+1] = returns[i+1]-mu-phi*returns[i]-theta*resid[i]

    # GARCH Portion
    sigma2 = omega/(1-alpha-beta)
    MLE = np.log(stat.norm.pdf(resid[0]/np.sqrt(sigma2)))
    for i in range(len(resid)-1):
        sigma2 = omega + alpha*(resid[i]**2) + beta*sigma2
        MLE += np.log(stat.norm.pdf(resid[i+1]/np.sqrt(sigma2), loc = 0, scale = 1))
    return MLE
```

I have reviewed this function more times than I can count, but perhaps there is an error that I am overlooking. Does this function look okay? If so, then the error must be in the optimization step.

Comment: @RichardHardy I changed it so it is less confusing, thanks.

Comment: A side note: in which sense do you mean OLS for ARMA if there is no (naive/direct) OLS estimator for ARMA given that the lagged error terms are unobserved?

Comment: @RichardHardy I rearranged the ARMA equation to solve for $\epsilon_t$. By assuming $\epsilon_0 = 0$ I can obtain $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, \ldots,\epsilon_n$ recursively. I used OLS to return the parameters that minimize the $L^2$ norm of these errors.

Comment: But you cannot obtain the errors recursively without having parameter estimates. This is why what you do is not OLS, as far as I can tell. It minimizes the square norm, yes, but this is not enough to call the procedure for OLS. E.g. you can have gradient descent that minimizes a square norm, but that would not be OLS.

Comment: @RichardHardy Maybe calling it OLS is incorrect then. What I did is create a function that returns some norm value (obtained from the procedure described earlier), I then used an optimization package to return $\mu, \theta$, and $\varphi$. However I scrapped this to instead do everything simultaneously using MLE.

Comment: OK, clarified. Thank you!